# Axios in a loop: how to skip an iteration if a request has failed?

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I have some array of endpoints:

```
const nodes = [127.111.111.222, 127.111.111.333, 127.111.111.444]
```

I am requesting each in a loop and collect response objects in another array:

```
let response
let nodes_data = []

// inside some async function
try{
    for(let node of nodes) {
        response = await axios.post(`http://${node}/`, {})
    
        nodes_data.push({ host: node, status: 'online', response: response.data})
    }
} catch(error) {
    console.log('Failed to request', error)
}
```

Right now if some endpoint fails to respond (note: not sending a 500+ or any other status code, but just does not respond at all) axios waits 5-7 seconds and turns  a runtime into 'catch' block (connection runtime error). The scripts stops to work.

How do I change everything so If a single endpoint runs out of time to respond, I still push an object into nodes_data with an 'offline' status and the loop continues to work?

Love <3

Comment: Hint: Put the try/catch _inside_ the loop instead

Answer (score 1):

I think using axios as a promise then block will help. I'm re-writing your code.

```
    for(let node of nodes) {
          axios.post(`http://${node}/`, {}).then(response =>
           {
             nodes_data.push({ host: node, status: 'online', response: response.data})
           }).catch(error =>{
             console.log(error);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [Promise.allSettled](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise/allsettled), which takes an array of promises and returns all the settled values, regardless of if they resolved or rejected.

```
let promises = nodes.map(node => {
    return axios.post(`http://${node}`, {});
});

let responses = Promise.allSettled(promises);

// you will get an array of values with the following signature:
// [
//   {status: "fulfilled", value: {"response": "from axios", "awesome": true},
//   {status: "rejected",  reason: Axios went poof!}
// ]
// ...
```